# Why Ctrl+S not working with shortcut.js in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, web-applications

I'm using [shortcut.js](http://www.openjs.com/scripts/events/keyboard_shortcuts/index.php). everything works fine but adding some shortcuts like Ctrl+S will not be captured by the library and pops up browser html saving panel.

**Working:**

```
shortcut.add("F3", function() {
        alert("انتخاب کالا");
    });
```

**Not working:**

```
shortcut.add("Ctrl+S", function() {
         alert("ذخیره");
    });
```